# How do I lock scaling in edit mode while still allowing translation and rotation?

Tags: hair

I am trying to model some hair using bezier curves as per the technique shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2XjdzzWCqI

Curves are mapped to the head, put into place with the handles, and given a bevel object. After having a ...thrilling time watching every attempt at modeling the hair crash (update to 2.79.6 fixed the issue), I came across a conundrum rather than a problem.

I want to make hair movement accessible via shape keys, such as a predefined shape suggesting that wind is affecting the hair. The thing though, is that while I get nice results from forming the key, the hair grows out. This is not a major issue since I can, you know, reshape it with proportional editing and all, but that is time consuming.

Is there a way to lock the scaling of the paths in the same way that the scaling of hair particles can be locked, but still be rotated and moved?

To put it another way, in the Imgur link below, note how Rigify lets the hand move around, but once the selected handle moves away from human proportions, the arm just stalls out while still looking human, as opposed to going all Elastigirl on us. This is due to IK stretch being turned off and yadda yadda. Anyway, is there a way to simulate that in edit mode with paths?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5cuC.jpg

Source of that specific rigify addon: http://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com/

Comment: A shapekey defines a new location for the vertices/curve points. It is a straight path from one location to another. You can use an armature with a curve, as vertex weights don't work you need to enable bone envelopes.

Comment: Why didn't I think of an armature if I showed one in my initial question? I'm smarter than that.

Well, apparently not.

Thanks! I'll give that a whirl -- kinda literally too.